# cx_freeze can't create exe because of encoding

Tags: python, encoding, cx-freeze

When i want to compile a file with non-ascii character in its name there is no problem. But when i want to add an icon to this executable my troubles appeared.

```
Executable('Tutoriál.pyw', base=base, icon=icon_tutorial)
```

This is setup.py.

```
running build
running build_exe
copying C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\bases\Win32GUI.exe -> build\exe.win-amd64-3.4\Tutoriál.exe
copying C:\Python34\python34.dll -> build\exe.win-amd64-3.4\python34.dll
error: [WinError 2] Systém nemůže nalézt uvedený soubor: 'build\\exe.win-amd64-3.4\\TutoriĂˇl.exe'
```

And this is error from build.

Answer (score 0):

I removed icon from executables and it worked in my case but I am also looking forward for answer for this question